# Let $X$ be compact, separable, metric space. Then every bijection is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be compact, separable, metric space.  Then every bijection is a homeomorphism?

I am extrapolating from an exercise that says,

Let $X$ be a compact separable metric space and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be injective.  Then $f(X)$ dense in $Y$ $\implies$ $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Is this right? Also, can I have a hint to the solution? I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is $Y$? And is $f$ a continuous map? By the way, every compact metric space is separable.

Answer (score 3):

No, your condition is not enough. Arbitrary bijection do not preserve any topological structure. Your claim is also not true for arbitrary $Y$. However, the following is known to be true:

If $X$ is a compact topological space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, then every continuous bijection $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism.

To see this: By assumption $f$ is bijective and continuous. So it suffices to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Let $C$ be a closed set. $C$ is compact since closed subsets of compact sets are compact. $f(C)$ is compact in $Y$ since image of compact sets are compact. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, compact sets are closed. So $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets. $f^{-1}$ is continuous. $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $f$ is continuous. Hint: $f(X)$ is compact.

Comment: The problem doesn't state that $f$ is continuous, do you think this is a typo then?

Comment: @user41728 If $f$ is an arbitrary function the result is false. For example,  take a bijection between $[0,1]$ and the irrationals.